# Why can't I 'heroku git:clone' and deploy my Strapi app?

Tags: heroku, strapi, heroku-postgres

I just deployed a brand new Strapi app on Heroku, and have seen it live. However, I tried to clone the Heroku CLI repository by doing the following:

1. `$ heroku login`
2. `$ heroku git:clone -a mentorsbackend`. //project name
3. `$ cd mentorsbackend`

deploying:

```
$ git add .
$ git commit -am "make it better"
$ git push heroku master
```

but when its all done I got this message:

```
heroku git:clone -a mentorsbackend                                                    Cloning into 'mentorsbackend'...
warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.
```

The issue is that the repo should contain my deployed Strapi project files in it. I can still see it live here: https://mentorsbackend.herokuapp.com/

Why can't I seem to be able to clone so I can work on it locally - Any or all responses will be very much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Why can't I seem to be able to clone so I can work on it locally

[This is an antipattern](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git-clone-heroku-app):

> A Heroku app’s Git repository is intended for deployment purposes only. Cloning from this repository is not officially supported as a feature and should be attempted only as a last resort. **Do not** use this repository as your app’s canonical “origin” repository. Instead, use your own Git server or a version control service such as GitHub.

Why can't you work from the local copy you already have, or clone from GitHub / GitLab / whatever your origin server is?

Having said that, if you deployed via `git push` you *should* be able to clone your source code. Are you sure you didn't deploy via GitHub integration? Or Docker? Those deployment options don't go through Heroku's Git repository.